# Ambiguity in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, legalese

Is this sentence ambiguous:

> Licensor grants licensee one license to install and use this software
>   on as many computers owned and operated by employees of your company

That is, who owns the computers?

if I change it in

> Licensor grants licensee one license to install and use this software
>   on as many computers owned by your company and operated by employees
>   of your company

it could mean that, if the company has 10 computers and the 20 employees each have a computer at home, the sentence would be about 30 computers.
However, the sentence must be about those 10 computers.

Comment: This isn't the place to fix your licensing agreements. In any case, I can't see why the 'operated by employees' line is needed, just give the license for only the computers owned by the company. And don't say 'your company', say the 'licensee'.

Comment: "English language & Usage"? It's not about giving licenses, but about the ambiguity creeping in by using the word "and". What is meant is easy to show in a Venn-diagram, but in language... that's another story, it seems. I could do it in my own language, Dutch, but how to do it in English? Fixing the problem by taking out the warning light bulb.... hmmm. But thanks anyway for your input.

Comment: ". . . as many computers _as are owned_. . .

Comment: or "... as many computers as licensee wishes". _As many_ with a forward reference is much better than with a backward reference (where it means  "as many computers as there are licenses."

Answer (score 0):

If the company has 10 computers and the 20 employees each have a computer at home, the sentence, literally taken, would be about 20 computers, not 30.  That's because the sentence is talking about computers that are both owned and operated by employees.  But likely no court in the US would interpret the language that way because to do so would make the agreement an invalid contract (because the company gets no benefit in exchange for paying the licensing fees).

curiousdannii has a point -- does it matter that the computers are operated by the company's employees?  I suppose it might if you want to preclude the company from re-deploying the software in the market by installing the software on its computers and charging the general public to operate those computers.  It that's the case, pass the following by your lawyer:

> Licensor grants licensee one license to install and use this software
>   on any computers owned or leased by the licensee and operated by
>   its officers, employees, or agents.

Comment: You say "Both owned and operated by employees". I was thinking of something like "Both owned by the company and operated by its employees". But would that indeed be unambiguous? I could still read 30 computers... If I think of a Venn-diagram to express the computers, I think of a balloon inside a balloon: the company has 10 computers (outer balloon) but only 7 of them (inner balloon) are operated by its employees in the course of their daily duties. the other 3 are not, somehow. Leased out or operated by external people or family of the CEO.

Comment: @Erik Are we saying different things?

Comment: Maybe so... Its difficult to remove this ambiguity. It is this damned little word "and". Dutch has the same problem. Computer languages do not have this problem. with "and" both conditions must be true.
Maybe :
....all computers owned by the company **but** also operated by its employees ?